# Headers en Retrofit con Android

Tags: android, retrofit, headers

He estado leyendo acerca de Retrofit y he llegado al punto de los Headers y no se si los he entendido demasiado bien. En el curso que estoy haciendo los usa para establecer una autentificación con un usuario creado en el backend y una base de datos y lo hace de dos formas diferentes:

```
private WebServiceBA() {

    loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(chain -> {

        Request original = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuild = original
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH_USER)
                .method(original.method(), original.body());
        Request request = requestBuild.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_BA)
            .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

En esta primera forma entiendo que está pasando el Header a través de código pero no entiendo el `.method(original.method(), original.body());`. Y en este está pasándolo a través de la propia llamada de Retrofit:

```
@GET("/todos_profesores_admin")
Call<List<ProfesorBA>> listAllProfesorAdmin(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

No entiendo si lo de "Authorization" es algo que debe ser así ya que está en el backend o es una forma de llamarlo en el código.

Supongo que al hacerlo en la llamada, en este caso tenemos más libertad ya que le pasamos los usuarios que nosotros queramos, pero ¿qué otras cosas podemos enviar a través del Header de una llamada de Retrofit o hasta donde se extiende su utilidad? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria usar el Interceptor para esos headers que vas a usar en la mayoria de tus endpoints por ejemplo todo lo que viene relacionado a la sesion. Tambien podes interceptar las respuestas y tratar ahí los problemas de sesion como la expiracion de un token. Los headers dentro de la llamada solo los uso en caso de que las llamadas lleven parametros metidos como headers o algun endpoint que necesite un header distinto los demas. Los parametros que pongas en el header dependen mucho de como esten armados los endpoints en el servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader
```

Esta es la forma que retrofit genera Headers de manera dinámica.
Ese valor de "**`Authorization`**" lo utilizara el backend para su proceso de seguridad.